# How to activate kerning in LibreOffice?

Tags: fonts, libreoffice

My fonts are horribly unkerned in LibreOffice. Example:

Here's a comparison, LibreOffice on top and Inkscape below.

[image: Comparison of Kerning between LibreOffice and Inkscape]

As you can see, LibreOffice messes up the kerning. The font is *Ubuntu, 10pt* in LibreOffice and *Ubuntu, 13px* in Inkscape.

The kerning problem gets less if I increase the font-size btw.

Is there a switch for activating the kerning in LibreOffice or is this a known problem?

Comment: The bad kerning only happens on screen. When you print the document or export it as PDF, kerning is nice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kerning is activated by using the Format->Character menu, selecting the Position tab and using the Pair kerning checkbox in the Spacing section.

[image]

Comment: The kerning seems still to be way off. (Maybe it's the font-hinting that screws it up.) Still, this activates kerning, so I'm marking it as correct. I wonder why this isn't activated by default.

Comment: That might be related to some regressions introduced with the switch to graphite2: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36703

Comment: I turned off kerning (was on by default as of LO shipped with Ubuntu 12.10) and had better results. The kerning is horrendous. I mean, it's epically bad. It's worse than Microsoft Word '98 kerning, OK, that's how bad it is. Letters just get sucked into their neighbours, or pushed away seemingly arbitrarily. It is not flattering to the LO suite of tools. *To be fair, this is only from screen display; print appears to have nice kerning.*

Answer (score 5):

Do a *"Select All"* before you turn kerning on. Otherwise it will apply only to a local selection, possible the current paragraph.

(I am using up to date libreoffice on a Mac, but this should still apply.)

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of kerning out there.  The old style involves pairs of letters while the new style, [GPOS kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning#Kerning_tables), supports pairing *groups* of letters. Adobe FontCreator and others now use GPOS and [GSUB](http://www.cairn.info/revue-document-numerique-2006-3-page-69.htm) rather than the "legacy" kern table method.

The [Linux Libertine](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=1&L=1) font project (Wikipedia's font of choice) [discusses kerning](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=87&L=1#c462):

> Nearly any good font contains kerning information, but how much time and effort the designer had spent on this feature is quite different. Until the late 1990s, the kerning information was defined in a long table pair by pair. Since OpenType there is the GPOS Kerning method, which allows a group by group approach. This is a much more elegant solution, because modern fonts with more than 2000 characters would otherwise contain thousands of entries.

The problem is that GPOS support is very rare.  [OpenOffice bug 31764](https://bz.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=31764) and [LibreOffice bug 46055](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46055) both request GPOS kerning support and neither seems to have much attention.

**2017 Update:** LO [resolved](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46055#c25) this in 2016/11. GPOS will be enabled by default in LibreOffice ~5.3.

Comment: I just learned something new today, thank you.